# find problems again?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, find

How do i show pipe or socked files from a directory?

```
echo "give name of directory: "
read directory
if  [ -d "$directory"   ]
then 
echo "thanks again"
else exit
fi
find $directory -maxdepth 1 -type f 
find $directory  -mtime -$integer2 -ls
find $directory -ctime -$integer2 -ls
```

Comment: You should try reading up on [man find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and go to the `-type` section which shows the different types of "files" that it can look for, including both pipes and sockets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `find` man page:

> ```
>    -type c
>           File is of type c:
>
>           b      block (buffered) special
>
>           c      character (unbuffered) special
>
>           d      directory
>
>           p      named pipe (FIFO)
>
>           f      regular file
>
>           l      symbolic link; this is never true if the -L option or the -follow option is in effect, unless the symbolic link is broken.  If you want to search for symbolic  links
>                  when -L is in effect, use -xtype.
>
>           s      socket
>
>           D      door (Solaris)
> ```

The flags you're looking for are `-type s` for sockets and `-type p` for pipes (or FIFO's)

EDIT: If you want to list files that are either a socket or a pipe then you'll need to specify an 'OR' in the command.  For example `find . \( -type s -o -type p \)`

Comment: what if i want to show both of them in one line?